# Fancybox Vimeo Video is not clickable (no fullscreen possible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

I display vimeo videos in my fancy box. The videos are shown but I can't click on the content of the fancy box if there is an vimeo video inside.

```
$('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    'width'  : 900, 
    'height' : 506,
    fitToView : false,
    autoSize: false,
    closeClick: false
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide us code o jsfiddle or which fancybox version you use??

Comment: It sounds like you are showing a gallery and the navigation area is blocking the controls. If so, check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No. 5 to move the navigation out of the fancybox content.